# How to delay javascript reload function on orientation change

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, delay

I am using a forced page reload on orientation change of the website and would like the page refresh to occur 5 seconds after the rotation occurs, but I cannot seem to put the timeout in the correct place.

Here is my code as it stands.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // RELOADS WEBPAGE WHEN MOBILE ORIENTATION CHANGES  
    window.onorientationchange = function() { 
        var orientation = window.orientation; 
            switch(orientation) { 
                case 0:
                case 90:
                case -90: window.location.reload(); 
                break; } 
    };
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you want it to reload after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout()` will help you achieve this

```
 case -90: setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.reload()
  },5000)
```

**UPDATE:** `window` does not have `orientation` property. It's the screen object which has `orientation` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Hence the `window.onorientation` handler has to be:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() { 
    var orientation = window.screen.orientation; 
        switch(orientation) { 
            case 0:
            case 90:
            case -90: window.location.reload(); 
            break; } 
};
```

Comment: This works exactly as I had hoped it would. Unfortunately still not arriving at the end result I am looking for, which is essentially a fresh re-draw of the page like when you first land....but the reload and replace options both remain affected by the change from landscape to portrait.

Comment: There is a bug in the code. I found that. We don't have window.orientation but window.screen.orientation

Comment: Try my updated answer. I am sure this will work for you :) Hopefully  and if it helps you do accept and vote my friend

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `setTimout()` function like this

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(); //this function will play after 5000 milliseconds
}, 5000);
```